# What are the ways of calculating Average Case's

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

**Background:** 
For my Data Structures and Algorithms I am studying the Big O Notation. So far I understand how to workout the time complexity, best and worst case scenario. However, the average case is just baffling my head. The teacher is just throwing at us equations that I don't understand. And he is not willing to explain them in detail. 
**Question:** 
So please guys, what is the best way to calculate this? Is there one equation that calculates this or does it vary from algorithm to algorithm? 
What are the steps you take to calculate this? 
Let's take an example of Insertion sort algorithm? 
**Research:** 
I looked on youtube and stackoverflow for answers. But they all use different equations. 
 
Any help would be great
thanks

Comment: It does vary from algorithm to algorithm. In each case, you need to think carefully about the possible inputs, and what the time complexity would be for each of them, and use that information to work out an average.

Comment: Average case analysis depends on average Input , Now what is average input? It is hard to determine. Most often all inputs are assumed to be equally likely to occur.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment you have to look at the average input to the algorithm (which in this case means random). A good way to think about it is to try at trace what the algorithm would do if the input was average.

For the example of insertion sort:

- In the best case (when the input is already sorted) the algorithm will look through the input but never exchanging anything, clearly resulting in a running time of O(n).
- In the worst case (when the input is exactly opposite if the desired order) the algorithm will move every input all the way from it's current position to the start of the list, that is, the object on index 0 will not be moved, the object on index 1 will be moved once, the object on input 2 will be moved twice and so on, resulting in a running time of 0+1+2+3+...+n-1 ≈ 0.5n² = O(n²).
- The same way of thinking can be used to find the average case, but instead of each object moving all the way to the start, we can expect that it will *on average* move halfway down to the start, that is, the object on index 0 will not be moved, the object on index 1 will be moved a half time (of cause this only makes sense *on average*), the object on input 2 will be moved once, the object on index 3 will be moved 1,5 times and so on, resulting in a running time of 0 + 0.5 + 1 + 1.5 + 2 + ... + (n-1)/2 ≈ 0.25n² (at each index, we have half of what we had in the worst case) = 0(n²).

Of cause not all algorithms are as simple as this, but looking at what the algorithm would do on each step if the input was random usually helps. If you have any kind of information available on the input to the algorithm, (for instance insertion sort is often used as the last step after an other algorithm has done most of the sorting, as it is very efficient if the input is almost sorted, and in such a case we might for example know that no object is going to be moved more than x times) then this can be taken into account when computing the average running time.